# Caffe - How to make 3 images in a data point train on same Convolution Layer

Tags: python, caffe

I am trying to implement a kind of an LSTM network. The LSTM needs to take feature maps from N images at multiple layers. Hence, these feature maps need to be computed in the same way for all N images. So the network would look something like this ideally:

[image]

The problem is that there doesn't seem to be a way in Caffe to do this. I can slice my data point (which consists of 3 images), into these 3 images, and I can run seperate Conv+Pool layers on it to get my feature maps. But this is not what I want during training. All three images need to have the same Conv + Pooling weights before being passed to the LSTM layered network. How can this be implemented.

I cannot use the concept of batch sizes here since I am training on a multi frame sequence, so each batch consists of M data points, which has 3 images each.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Caffe, but it sounds like what you want is to have a single conv+pool work on 3 different images at a time. You can usually accomplish this via a shared layer feature in a deep learning framework (AFAIK, this feature should be pretty standard). So perhaps look for how to share weights between layers, or how to share layers between inputs, in Caffe? As an example, this is how you would share a layer in Keras: https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#shared-layers

Comment: yeah i know all this is possible in keras and TF. This is a normal thing to do in LSTM implementations. Unfortunately, all the systems in my company are built around caffe, so I am trying to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the slice after the conv layer, so you would have applied the exact same weights to the 3 images. I quickly edited your image with the idea.[image]